# How to use another loop inside for loop in JSON in API use php

Tags: php, html, arrays

here is my php code in which i want some more configurations.....

```
<?php  
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($json['TrainRoute']); $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['SerialNo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['StationName'];  ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ScheduleArrival'];  ?> / <?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ScheduleDeparture']; ?></td>

            <td class="train-mobile"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ActualArrival'];  ?> / <?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ActualDeparture'];  ?></td>

            <td class="train-mobile"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['Day'];  ?></td>
            <td style="color: red;"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['DelayInDeparture']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php  }  ?>
```

In the above code, i want to insert the following condition..

```
    <td style="color: green;">     
       <?php 
           if ( $json['TrainRoute']['StationName'] = $json['CurrentStation']['StationName'] ) {
               echo $json['CurrentStation']['StationName'];
              }                                    
               ?>    
      </td>
```

So that when i display, below code comes with the above code but the below code will display only once.

When I simply paste below code in above code, below code display with every repetition of above code, but I want it to display only once at the current position.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry didn't getting you properly, please update it a bit. Why you have to td for green?

Comment: You cannot place a `<td>` inside a `<td>` like that. Maybe if you explain why you think you want to do this we can help

Comment: You need to use two equals in the if statement in your second snippet: `$json['TrainRoute']['StationName'] == $json['CurrentStation']['StationName']`

Comment: this appears to have nothing directly to do with JSON or APIs, it's simply about PHP arrays and displaying some HTML. Edited the tags

Comment: by mistake, <td> was used used twice, i have edited it

Answer (score 2):

Within your if statement, you are assigning a value to the array this will always evaluate to true, and thus the if statement will never fail;

```
$json['TrainRoute']['StationName'] = $json['CurrentStation']['StationName']
```

This is because you're using a single equals

It should be a double or triple equals for comparison, or strict comparison respectively;

```
$json['TrainRoute']['StationName'] == $json['CurrentStation']['StationName']
```